# PHP Insert an array as a string into mysql text field

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array inside this variable:

```
$myArray;
```

Then I'm inserting it into the database where I have a text field:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO myTable (thetextfield) VALUES ('$myArray')");
```

The problem is that I've looked in the table content and it just says "Array" (without the quotes).

Is there not a way to insert the array as it is or separate them by commas and insert them?

Comment: Often a bad idea.... but serialize() on insert and unserialize() on read

Comment: `implode(',',$myArray)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to insert a divisor, like:

```
$arrayString = implode(",", $myArray);
```

But if a string containing a `,` is in `$myArray` this could cause unexpected results while converting back to an array, because you would suddenly have one more array item. (To convert it back you can use `explode`)

You can also use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the array to JSON.

```
$arrayString = json_encode($myArray);
```

which is much safer. (To decode back to an array use `json_decode`)

And of course you can just serialize the PHP array:

```
$arrayString = serialize($myArray);
```

The con of this option is that the output string can only be read by PHP, unlike JSON which is widely supported.
(`unerialize` can be used to convert the string back to an array)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your array before saving it and unserialize it again after retrieving from db,

```
"INSERT INTO myTable (thetextfield) VALUES ('".serialize($myArray)."')"
```

If you want to save it comma separated use implode function to achieve that,

```
"INSERT INTO myTable (thetextfield) VALUES ('".implode (", ", $myArray)."')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$newString = implode(",", $myArray);
"INSERT INTO myTable (thetextfield) VALUES ('$newString')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert a array directly to mysql as mysql will not recognize it.

You need to convert the array either using php implode or you can use serialize or json_encode with php..In that way it will be easier for you to retrieve array data as well.

Comment: You should've just upvoted the answer that's the same as your idea rather than giving another answer.

Comment: yes, actually when I was answering the question there was no answer for this question.